# If you want to train a model on the predictions of another trained model, would you use the same training set for both model?

Tags: model-evaluation, validation, stacking

Imagine I train a model and make predictions on it, denoting the training data by x_train and the predictions by y_pred_train.

Then, I want to use those predictions in a second ML model. Would you use the same y_pred_train to train your model, or instead, predictions from unseen data during the training of the first model, say y_pred_train_unseen?

Note than in both cases I would evaluate the final performance on unseen data.

Thanks